# Standard ML : Calculating the average of a given set

Tags: functional-programming, average, sml

I recently had the assignment to calculate the average of a set (given by input) in Standard ML.

The idea is to have a function like below in which you input a list of real numbers and receive the average of those numbers (also a real), such that the terminal gives you this as a return answer when you input the function:

```
average = fn : real list -> real
```

We discussed this in a tutorial as well but I wanted to know if there was some sort of trick when creating such functions in Standard ML.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sum the numbers and divide by the length. A simple recursive `sum` is typically one of the first examples that you would see in any SML tutorial. You would need to have the empty list basis case of `sum` evaluate to `0.0` rather than `0` to make sure that the return type is `real`. Once you define a `sum` function then you can define `average` in 1 line using `sum` and the built in `length` function. A subtlty is that SML doesn't allow a real to be divided by an int. You could use the conversion function `Real.fromInt` on the length before dividing the sum by it. There is some inefficiency in passing over the same list twice, once to sum it and once to calculate its length, but there is little reason to worry about such things when you are first learning the language.

On Edit: Since you have found a natural solution and shared it in the comments, here is a more idiomatic version which computes the average in one pass over the list:

```
fun average nums =
    let
        fun av (s,n,[]) = s/Real.fromInt(n)
        |   av (s,n,x::xs) = av (s+x,n+1,xs)
    in
        av (0.0, 0, nums)
    end;
```

It works by defining a *helper function* which does the heavy lifting. These are used extensively in functional programming. In the absence of mutable state, a common trick is to explicitly pass as parameters quantities which would be successively modified by a corresponding loop in an imperative language. Such parameters are often called `accumulators` since they typically accumulate growing lists, running sums, running products, etc. Here `s` and `n` are the accumulators, with `s` the sum of the elements and `n` the length of the list. In the basis case of `(s,n,[])` there is nothing more to accumulate so the final answer is returned. In the non-basis case, `(s,n,x::xs)`, `s` and `n` are modified appropriately and passed to the helper function along with the tail of the list. The definition of `av` is [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) hence will run with the speed of a loop without growing the stack. The only thing that the overall `average` function needs to do is to invoke the helper function with the appropriate initial values. The `let ... helper def ... in ... helper called with start-up values ...end` is a common idiom used to prevent the top-level of a program from being cluttered with helper functions.

Comment: A+ for providing guidance/explanation to a student instead of just giving an answer that doesn't teach anything.

Comment: @john Thank you for the help!  In the tutorial we discused doing this with several functions. We weren't supposed to use any build in libraries (i.e. Real.fromInt). So I tried it with the multiple functions method and got something like this (which works):


**sum function:**
`fun sum (h::t)=h + sum(t) | sum(nil)=0.0;`

**length function:**
`fun length(h::t) = 1.0 + length(t) | length(nil) = 0.0;`


**Complete function:**
`fun average(l) = sum(l) / length(l);`

Comment: @opheliaxo Nice. I find it slightly more natural to put the basis case before the recursive case, but that is mostly a matter of taste and perhaps convention. Since I no longer have to worry about doing someone's homework before they have the pleasure of figuring it out on their own, I edited my answer to include what I regard as the most idiomatic and efficient way to compute the average in SML.

Answer (score 1):

Since only non-empty lists can have averages, an alternative on John Coleman's answer is:

```
fun average [] = NONE
  | average nums =
    let
        fun av (s,n,[]) = s/Real.fromInt(n)
          | av (s,n,x::xs) = av (s+x,n+1,xs)
    in
        SOME (av (0.0, 0, nums))
    end;
```

Whether a function for calculating averages should take non-empty lists into account depends on whether you intend to export it or only use it within a scope in which you guarantee elsewhere that the input list is non-empty.